# Extract $_GET/$_POST params and pass them to constructor

Tags: php

For example, `$_GET` contains `id=10, var=100`. How can I extract and pass them to constructor `public function __construct($id, $var)` Something like this `new Test(extract($_GET));`

Comment: You might want to $_POST some accepted answers.

Comment: Yes, please accept answers when you find them helpful/correct.

Also, did you want to pass the key and the value, or just the value?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ReflectionMethod`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.construct.php) from [reflection API](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to check what's the signature of `__construct()` method.

```
class MyClass {
        public function __construct($id, $title, $slug = null) {
                var_dump($id, $title, $slug);
        }
}

$object = new MyClass();

$method = new ReflectionMethod($object, '__construct');
$parameters = $method->getParameters();
```

`$parameters` contains an array of [`ReflectionParameter`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionparameter.php) objects.

Now you need to prepare an array of parameters that will be used by [`ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invokeargs.php):

```
$invokeParameters = array();

foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
    $value = $_REQUEST[$parameter->getName()]; 

    $invokeParameters[$parameter->getPosition()] = $value;
}

$method->invokeArgs($object, $invokeParameters);
```

Of course you should add a few conditions to check whether all mandatory parameters exist within `$_REQUEST`, throw exception if not, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you know what values you are  looking for from the URL?

$_GET in PHP is just an associative array. So if my url looks like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?var1=foo&var2=bar
```

I can get those variables like so:

```
new Test($_GET['var1'], $_GET['var2']);
```

Be careful with $_GET as there is no safeguard that prevents me from changing my URL bar to

```
    http://example.com/index.php?var1=foo&var2=[malicious code]
```

So you should always treat it as untrusted.

Comment: He wants both the key and the value to be passed to the constructor. Not just the value.

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor to __construct($array); and the set you variables inside the construtor. It's not pretty and I would not recomend it, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is an associative array. So you could get the [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) from `$_GET` to get the variable name. The value is obviously `$_GET['key']`